# CentOS 5.8 broke server by accident.. Can I fix it?

Tags: centos

I have a problem... I was trying to rm -rf * one of my folders, but it turns out I was in the / directory... I stopped the command quickly but it still broke  A LOT of things. Almost all commands are broken... LS returns /usr/bin/LS not found... Is there some way that I can reinstall CentOS without loosing all of my data and just repairing what was broken? If there is anything I can do without loosing my data, I would REALLY appreciate it. I took lots of time setting up this server. Oh and I can mount ISO on the server...

Comment: I'm actually surprised that worked, normally it would require the `--no-preserve-root` flag.  In any case, I would do what Fred suggests.  Otherwise you'll spend way too much time trying to replace folders/files/programs and never get it quite right.

Comment: @nerdwaller `--preserve-root` will protect from deleting `/` but not `/usr` etc.

Comment: I thought that may be the case, though i tried it in a vm and got an error, so wasn't fully sure. Thanks @terdon !

Comment: @nerdwaller well, for obvious reasons, I have never tried it but that's how I understand the man page :). I would guess that `rm -rf /` is not allowed but the OP ran `rm -rf *` while in `/` and that is a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take the drive, attach it to a good system, and copy off what user data was left, put it back, then do a clean reinstall. That will give you a known good OS and I suspect it will be faster than trying to fix problems as you find them.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `/home` on a separate partition? If so, you can reinstall, and use the same `/home`. Any data you have not deleted will still be there.

If it is not on a separate partition, you can either move the drive to another computer as suggested by @Fred, or you can boot into a live CD and retrieve any remaining data from there. In any case, you will need to reinstall afterwards.

To avoid this in the future, you may want to make `rm` an alias to `rm -I` :

```
   -I     prompt  once  before removing more than three files, or
          when removing recursively.   Less  intrusive  than  -i,
          while still giving protection against most mistakes
```

Comment: My home is not on a seperate partition.. I dont think it is, and most of my needed data is in /root.

Comment: Why in the world would you keep your data in `/root`?!? Anyway, in that case, boot into a live session, copy whatever is left to an external drive and reinstall.

Comment: Good suggestion on the live CD!